# What's the best way to export huge Magento catalogs

Tags: php, magento, export

I am reading a ton of docs about Magento's API, Magento's Models and Direct SQL calls. As I was reading that, the first conclusion is that direct sql calls would be very faster but I must take a special care at security, and the use of models make the development faster and easier but in the other hand, it loses performance manipulating huge catalogs.

I will have to deal with a shop with around 50k of products & heavy traffic, and I must export them to another server with category hierarchy, sku, description, image, product_name, url_path once and after it get only the updated ones once a hour. The best approach would be with direct sql calls, but will it be a suicide to make it with models? And do you think that integrate it with the SOAP API will be another suicide, and I should make it in a separate PHP to do this?

Super thanks in advance, I am very lost at this, and sorry for my bad English
Vinicius

Comment: "will it be a suicide" - I see you're well experienced with magento already! :D

Comment: don't forget images too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many considerations here. I'm speaking about this because I have a similar issue. I'm currently using SQL to get the data from magento store to xml. Truely, using sql can make it faster ONLY if you know the attributes you're fetching. eg. if your products have 15 attibutes, that means 50k x 15 attributes using sql. But at least you'll be free from version issues because you're using sql statements.

On the other hand...using models and API gives a lot of version issues especially if you're developing for several magento versions. One other problem too is about magento custom attributes. Eg. If i add another attribute called 'US SPECIAL SHIPPING', It becomes quite difficult with the API.

If you don't mind...you just make a direct sql call to all your attributes and save them to xml. That means you need very very fast machine to do this.

There is an extension on magento connect that serves comparison engines. It may fit your export neeeds. try it. [price comparison script](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/feed-manager-version-1-1-3.html)

```
<?php 

set_time_limit(3000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
include_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->load(); 
$baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);                       
    $output = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <products>';
if (count($products)): 

  foreach ($products as $id => $product):

  $url = $product->getProductUrl();
  $output .= '
  <product>
  <id>'. $product['entity_id'].'</id>
  <name><![CDATA['. $product['name'] .']]></name>
  <sku>'. $product['sku'] .'</sku>
  <description><![CDATA['. $product['description'] .']]></description>
  <shortdescription><![CDATA['. $product['short_description'] .']]></shortdescription>
  <price><![CDATA['. $product['price'] .']]></price>
  <minimalprice>'. $product['minimal_price'] .'</minimalprice>   
  <weight><![CDATA['. $product['weight'] .']]></weight>
  <categories><![CDATA['. $product['categories'] .']]></categories>
  <color><![CDATA['. $product['color'] .']]></color>
  <condition><![CDATA['. $product['condition'] .']]></condition>
  <availability><![CDATA['. $product['availability'] .']]></availability>
  <shipping><![CDATA['. $product['shipping'] .']]></shipping>
  <url><![CDATA['. $url.']]></url>
  <meta><![CDATA['. $product['meta_keyword'] .']]></meta>
  <metadescription><![CDATA['. $product['meta_description'] .']]></metadescription>
  <manufacturer><![CDATA['. $product['manufacturer'] .']]></manufacturer>
  <brand><![CDATA['. $product['brand'] .']]></brand>
  <upc><![CDATA['. $product['upc'] .']]></upc>
  <mpn><![CDATA['. $product['mpn'] .']]></mpn>
  <image><![CDATA['. $baseUrl ."media/catalog/product". $product['image'] .']]>        </image>';
  if (isset($attributes[$product['entity_id']])) {
  $output .= '
  <attributes>';  
  foreach ($attributes[$product['entity_id']] as $attribute => $values)
   $output .= '
    <attribute>
     <name>'. $attribute .'</name>
      <values>'.  join(', ', $values) . '</values>
     </attribute>';  
   $output .= '
 </attributes>';
  }

$output .= '
</product>';
endforeach;
endif;
header ("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
print $output .= '
 </products>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was testing the server overhead and it would be too resource eater to do it all at once, as the server already has a heavy access everytime. So my idea was to make a script using models as the other guy mentioned, because making direct sql calls will be difficult as I'll need to deal with a lot of different Magento versions and I want to make it to work with the next future updates without have to worry too. So I'll make it more interactive by getting only the data that I'll use at the time, and then cache it on the third party server and only when it expires

Comment: I will request this data again to the server.

Comment: Great solution! How would I go about to make this into a CSV file?

Comment: the xml files can be downloaded changed to csv with MSExcel

Answer (score 1):

1) soap api over live server for 50K products will be very slow. 
2) direct sql calls would be very cumbersome to write because of EAV structure
3) to prevent hogging of the live server, take a read replica of the database, use it to install magento on local/another server. and work on that.

Comment: I took it in mind, and I'll use models in a separated PHP instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem when exporting my Magento products to Google Shopping. It always timed out (probably due to having too many products in my feed).

After doing some research into [magento exporting](http://www.internetmarketing.net/2014/blog/how-to-export-magento-product-feed-for-google-shopping.html), I tried changing my php.ini settings to these values:

```
ini_set(’max_execution_time’,’1800’);
ini_set(’memory_limit’,’1024M’);
```

and it worked perfectly!